# Configure Apache as reverse proxy for Grafana

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, reverse, grafana

I tried to configure reverse proxy to enable auto login using the domain (IP) using this - http://docs.grafana.org/installation/behind_proxy/#running-grafana-behind-a-reverse-proxy. I am not able to view without login.

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@authproxy
 ServerName authproxy
 ErrorLog "logs/authproxy-error_log"
 CustomLog “logs/authproxy-access_log” common

 <Proxy *>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName GrafanaAuthProxy
   AuthBasicProvider file
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/grafana_htpasswd
   Require valid-user
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXY_USER:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER},NS]
   RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER "%{PROXY_USER}e"
 </Proxy>
 RequestHeader unset Authorization
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPass / http://IP:3000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://IP:3000/
```

content of /etc/apache2/grafana_htpasswd grafanaid:grafanapwd

grafana.ini

```
 ;domain = http://IP
 ;root_url = http://IP:3000/
 #################################### Auth Proxy ##########################
 [auth.proxy]
 ;enabled = true
 ;header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
 ;header_property = username
 ;auto_sign_up = true
 ;ldap_sync_ttl = 60
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://grafana.com/blog/2015/12/07/grafana-authproxy-have-it-your-way/)?